# JQuery clearing an input text field

Tags: jquery, syntax

I have a question regarding clearing an input text field when a different drop down on teh same page is clicked, the value in the input text field should be cleared. Here is my jQuery ftn. The alert message is shown everytime I select an option from drop down but the field does not get cleared. Any idea what the correct syntax should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery("[id$='serialNumForm:noSerialNumProductKey']").change(function () {
            alert("In jquery change ftn!!");
            jQuery("[id$='serialNumForm:inputSN']").value="";
        });     
    });
```

I have a form Id  so  I need to prepend the Id to the element id name. the alert displays fine just the value does not change.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to use:

```
jQuery("[id$='serialNumForm:inputSN']").val("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling "jQuery("[id$='serialNumForm:inputSN']")" doesn't return you an input element - instead it returns you a jQuery object. You have two options:

Use this to get the core element:

```
jQuery("[id$='serialNumForm:inputSN']").get(0)
```

Or, as Justin mentioned, use the jQuery val() method:

```
jQuery("[id$='serialNumForm:inputSN']").val("");
```

The second way is more reliable, since it applies the value to all matching elements, while the first only applies it to the first matching element (as indicated by the 0 in the get(0) )

Comment: You can also do jQuery("[id$='serialNumForm:inputSN']")[0] to get that dom element since the jQuery object is an array.